# Converting CSV to DB for SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, csv

I am trying to convert a .csv file I've download into a .db so that I can analyze it in DBreaver with SQLite3.

I'm using Anaconda Prompt and python within it.

Can anyone point out where I'm mistaken?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite 3

df = pd.read_csv('0117002-eng.csv')
df.to_sql('health', conn)
```

And I just haven't been able to figure out how to set up conn appropriately. All the guides I've read have you do something like:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("file.db")
```

But, as I mentioned I have only the csv file. And when I did try to do that, it also doesn't work.

Comment: you need to have `file.db` existing already

Comment: `connect` will create a new database if the file does not yet exist.

Comment: Did you even try to connect to it? Because it will create a db file for you if one doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, that worked!

I hadn't created the file.db, as I was trying different iterations that made intuitive sense (based on my insufficient understanding.)

Thank you for the help.